# Ajax function not returing anything in response but post is working fine: Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, forms, function, email

I have this ajax script that action on a function in function.php to send an email after submitting the form. Data is posting but the function is not triggering and so the email is not sending , also script is not showing anything in response.

```
              ==================Jquery====================
jQuery('#quote-forms').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var ocity = jQuery(".ocity").val();
    var ostate = jQuery(".ostate").val();
    var ozip = jQuery(".ozip").val();
    var dataString = 'custom ocity='+ ocity + '&custom ostate=' + ostate + '&custom ozip=' + ozip;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        action : 'quote_ajax_submission',
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {  
        alert("sent");
        } 
        });          
    });
```

And here is my function in function.php file can you please check and let me know what is the issue so no response in return and email is not sending.

```
        add_action('wp_ajax_quote_ajax_submission', 'quote_ajax_handler');
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_quote_ajax_submission','quote_ajax_handler');
  function quote_ajax_handler(){

echo "helol";

$oCity          = $_POST["custom ocity"];
$iZip           = $_POST["custom ozip"];
$oState         = $_POST["custom ostate"];
$dState         = $_POST["dstate"];
$dZip           = $_POST["dzip"];
$dCity          = $_POST["dcity"];
$rNumbers       = $_POST["room-numbers"];
$mDate          = $_POST["mdate"];
$fName          = $_POST["fname"];
$lName          = $_POST["lname"];
$pEmail         = $_POST["pemail"];
$pPhone         = $_POST["pphone"];
$addtion_C      = $_POST["additionC"];

$to = 'shoaibswl123@gmail.com';

$subject = 'Quote Request From '. $fName ;

$message = '<html><body>'; 

$message = '<div style="background:#CEE4ED; padding:10px;>';
$message = '<div style="margin-left:30px;">';
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<br>";

$message .= "<b>Hi Admin,</b>";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= 'You have received a new quote from the site with the following information';

$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<br>";

$message .= '<b>Address Information:</b>';

$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<br>";


$message .= "<b>Origin City: </b>" .$oCity;
$message .= "<br />";
$message .= "<b>Origin Zip: </b>" . $iZip; 
$message .= "<br />";
$message .= "<b>Origin State: </b>" . $oState;
$message .= "<br />";
$message .= "<b>Destination City: </b>" .$dCity;
$message .= "<br />";
$message .= "<b>Destination Zip: </b>" .$dZip;
$message .= "<br />";
$message .= "<b>Destination State: </b>" .$dState; 

$message .= "<hr>";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<br>";

$message .= '<b>Client Information:</b>'; 
$message .= "<br />";
$message .= "<br />";
$message .= "<b>First Name: </b>" .$fName;
$message .= "<br />";
$message .= "<b>Last Name: </b>" .$lName;
$message .= "<br />";
$message .= "<b>Primary Emai: </b>" .$pEmail;
$message .= "<br />";
$message .= "<b>Primary Phone: </b>" .$pPhone;
$message .= "<hr>";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<br>";

$message .= '<b>Moving Information:</b>'; 

$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<br />";

$message .= "<b>Moving Date: </b>" .$mDate;
$message .= "<br />";
$message .= "<b>Number of Rooms: </b>" .$rNumbers;

$message .= "<hr>";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<br>";

$message .= '<b>Addition Comments :</b>';
$message .= "<br />";
$message .= '<p>'.$addtion_C.'</p>' ;

$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<br>";

$message .= "<p>Thank you.</p>";

$message .= "</div></div>";

$message .= "</body></html>";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'From: '.$pEmail.'' . "\r\n";


   if(wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){

    echo "<div class='success-message'>Message Has Been Sent Successfully..!</div>";

   }else{

     echo "<div class='success-message'>There is an error while sending message..!</div>";
   }

   die();
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute path to your wp-admin/admin-ajax.php instead of relative path? Also, you should always have the error function defined with your ajax call so that you can see if there is an error returned instead of success: error: function (jqXHR, exception) { and console.log the error returned to help you debug.

Comment: So the absolute path will be like this? and i added the error function but it doesn't return any error 
url: 'ABSPATH./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', @MirzaP

Answer (score 0):

There was issue with action element in ajax call.

so we have updated the code like this and added the action element in the data array and its work as follows:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: 'action=quote_ajax_submission&'+dataString,
        success: function(data) {  
        alert("sent");
        },
        error: function(request, status, error){
        alert(request.responseText); 

        }
        });          
    });
```

So before the updated code the action element was like this:

```
 action : 'quote_ajax_submission',
```

After update the code action like this...

```
 data: 'action=quote_ajax_submission&'+dataString,
```